# Debug Assertion Failed. BIG_ALLOCATION_ALLIGNMENT

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to take user inputted notes and store them in an array. The validation works fine but when I input the last value in the loop I get:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: "(_Ptr_user & (_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT - 1))==0"&&0
An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

I'm struggling to understand where the issue is and how I can fix it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef string noteName;

noteName getNoteName(int i)
{
    bool flag = true;
    noteName Namein;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter note name no. " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> Namein;
        cout << "------------------------------------\n";

        if (Namein.length() > 3 || Namein.length() < 2)
        {
            cout << "Sorry, a note name must be 2 or 3 characters long. Please try again.\n";
            flag = false;
        }
        else if (Namein.length() == 3 && Namein[1] != '#')
        {
            cout << "Sorry, the second character of a sharp note name must be #. Please try again.\n";
            flag = false;
        }
        else if ((Namein[0] < 'a' || Namein[0] > 'g') && (Namein[0] < 'A' || Namein[0] > 'G'))
        {
            cout << "Sorry, the first character of a note name must be a letter between A and G. Please try again.\n";
            flag = false;
        }
        else if (isdigit(Namein.back()) == false)
        {
            cout << "Sorry, the last character of a note name must be a number. Please try again.\n";
            flag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    } while (flag == false);

    return Namein;
}

int main()
{
   const int numNotes = 4;

    noteName NoteNames[numNotes];

    cout << "Hello\n";

    for (int i = 0; i <= numNotes; i++)
    {
        NoteNames[i] = getNoteName(i);
    }

    cout << "Thank you, the note names and lengths you entered were: \n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i <= numNotes; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ". " << NoteNames[i] << "\n";
    }

    cout << "Done!";

    return 0;
}
```

I want to say it's something to do with `getNoteName()` having a `string` return type as I haven't had this issue with any of my other functions that return `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`noteName NoteNames[numNotes];` defines an array where `NoteNames[numNotes - 1]` is the largest element you can access.

You go one further than this. The behaviour on doing that is *undefined* which is manifesting itself as the crash that you observe.

Replace your loop limits with `for (int i = 0; i < numNotes; i++)`, or similar.

(You also have your CamelCase conventions for class names and variable names switch round from what's normal, which makes your code confusing to read.)

(I'd also rather see `constexpr int numNotes = 4;`: Google that for more details.)